# Error converting nvarchar to int inside a dynamic ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Code:

```
DECLARE @SortOrder nvarchar(max); 
SET @SortOrder = 'name';
SELECT * FROM [database_name].[schema_name].[table_name] 
ORDER BY CASE @SortOrder
    WHEN 'id' THEN id 
    WHEN 'name' THEN name 
    END;
```

Output:
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'foo' to data type int.

When I instead put @SortOrder = 'id', it works flawlessly.  When I do a normal SELECT and ORDER BY name, it also works flawlessly.

Why would it try to convert that nvarchar value to data type int, and how can I stop it from doing so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`CASE` is an expression that returns a single value of a specific data type. The potential values must be compatible, and since you must have a name value of `foo`, which can't be converted to `INT`, you get this error. The easiest way to solve this problem is to separate your `ORDER BY` expressions by data type:

```
ORDER BY CASE @SortOrder WHEN 'id' THEN id END,
         CASE @SortOrder WHEN 'name' THEN name END;
```

Another alternative (which may be better for plan caching as long as you have `optimize for ad hoc workloads` on) would be dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ... ORDER BY ' + QUOTENAME(@SortOrder) + ';';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Also not sure why you would give your `@SortOrder` a max data type - no column name could ever be anywhere near that large.

Comment: I prefer option 1 because of: SET @SortOrder =N'1; DROP TABLE tblname;';

Comment: @EdwardDortland Well of course, I don't think we need to scope creep an entire dynamic SQL conversation into this. These inputs may be guarded enough where performance is more important, and hopefully the executing user doesn't have `DROP` permissions in the first place - that's a different issue entirely. Anyway, `QUOTENAME()` should help.

Answer (score -2):

All routes through a case statement must output the same data type. Try casting the ID to a string like this and it will work.

```
DECLARE @SortOrder nvarchar(max); 
SET @SortOrder = 'name';
SELECT * FROM [database_name].[schema_name].[table_name] 
ORDER BY CASE @SortOrder
    WHEN 'id' THEN cast(id AS NVARCHAR(20))
    WHEN 'name' THEN name 
    END;
```

Comment: No, this won't work very well at all. 9 will sort after 32, for example.

Comment: Indeed, I had just spotted that flaw.